# $f$ has a local maximum at a point $x \in E$. Prove that $f'(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Suppose that $f$ is a differentiable real function in an open set $E \subset \mathbb{R^n}$, and that $f$ has a local maximum at a point $x \in E$. Prove that $f'(x)=0$

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_%28stationary_points%29#Proof).

Comment: Do you really mean $\Bbb R^n$? The notation $f'(x)$ only applies to one variable functions.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski yes it is

Comment: @MatthewLeingang tried using the definition, but not got nothing conclusive

Comment: Well you have inconsistencies with the notation. I suspect $\Bbb R^1$ is what was intended.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski excuse me but I need the result to $\mathbb{R^n}$

Comment: @TimRaczkowski If $f'(x)$ is interpreted as $\nabla f(x)$ and $0$ is the zero vector it would make sense.

Comment: @João have you tried the case $n=1$ or $n=2$? Have you drawn a picture?

Comment: @Matthew Forthe case $n = 1$ could demonstrate

Comment: Then add that into your question.  This is a question and answer site, not a proof machine.

Comment: For what it's worth, the only differentiability assumption you need is that the derivative exists (finitely) at the local minimum point. Indeed, the function can be discontinuous at every other point in $E.$ Note that abel's answer implicitly shows this, since only differentiability at $x=a$ and being defined in a neighborhood of $x=a$ are used in abel's answer.

Answer (score 1):

this is the case for $n=1.$ what is $f^\prime(x)$ for $x$ in $R^n, n > 1?$

you can argue by contradiction. suppose $f$ has a local maximum and $f^\prime(a) \neq 0.$  we can assume that $f^\prime(a) > 0$ for if not take $-f$ instead.

since $f^\prime(a) > 0,$ from the definition of derivative you have 
$\dfrac{1}{2}f^\prime(a) \le \dfrac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} \le \dfrac{3}{2}f^\prime(a)$
for $x$ suffciently near $a.$ this can be rewrittens as 
$$f(a) + \dfrac{1}{2}f^\prime(a)(x-a) \le f(x) \le f(a) + \dfrac{3}{2}f^\prime(a)(x-a) $$
this implies $f$ is increasing around $a$ and contradicts that $f$ has a local maximum at $x = a.$

Comment: This is a demonstration for the case $n=1$, I think the author wants to know the general case

Comment: @Croos. thanks for the reminder. i will add that qualification. my bad.

Comment: @abel I'm following the notation of the book Principles of Mathematical Analysis - Walter Rudin

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that at some point $p=(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n)$ and for some $i$, we have  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=c\neq0$.

We can regard $f$ as a differentiable function in a single variable $t$, where you only vary $x_i=t$ and leave $x_j$ constant for $j\neq i$. Denote this as $g(t)$. By definition, $g'(p_i)=c$.

Clearly $g(t)$ does not have a local maximum at $t=p_i$. It follows that $f(x)$ does not have a local maximum at $x=p$.